# conversion from "float" to "non-scalar" type requested error in c++

Tags: c++

i'm working to a boid simulation on c++. i'm coding the euclidean geometry but i got stuck on this problem.

my code is

```
vettore vettore::sottduevet(const vettore& v, const vettore& v1){
  vettore differenza =(v.x-v1.x, v.y-v1.y);
  return std::move(differenza);
};
```

but the compiler gives me an error, the constructor has been coded like

```
 vettore(){};
  vettore(float a,float b){
    x = a;
    y = b;
  };
```

so i really don't know why the compiler requires a type conversion for the variable "differenza".
how can i procede?

Comment: `vettore differenza =(v.x-v1.x, v.y-v1.y);` --> `vettore differenza =vettore(v.x-v1.x, v.y-v1.y);` or more simply `vettore differenza(v.x-v1.x, v.y-v1.y);`

Comment: Or just `return {v.x-v1.x, v.y-v1.y};`. (The expression `(v.x-v1.x, v.y-v1.y)` is equivalent to `v.y-v1.y`. Read about the comma operator in your favourite C++ book.)

Comment: You also don't need to `move` on return.

Comment: and the `move` could be slowing things down by messing with elision.

Comment: It would probably help others help you if you post the error message you are getting from the compiler.